# Infinite hour and minute picker

Tags: javascript, html

How to implement an infinite hour and minute picker like iOS does?
[image]
Or something like Microsoft Edge `<input type="time" />`
[image]
Notice that it's like a circular loop. Using only JavaScript without any libraries would be awesome

Comment: You are answering your own question. Use `<input type="time" />`, there's nothing wrong with it and will save you lots of unnecessary development time.

Comment: `<input type="time" />` doesn't work the same in Firefox like it does in Microsoft Edge. Also, I would like to know how it's done

Comment: The browser chooses the design and how it's done. The only way to do it is to custom make it and spend hours of development time.

Comment: If you want to know how it's done, have a look at the source of the various browsers, they are all open source. If you want to have a try at writing one yourself, go for it and if you have specific problems, feel free to come ask about those here. It's unclear what your question currently is. (actually, Safari and most of Opera aren't open source, the others are though)

Comment: There are some closed source browsers, but most of them are open source. @Grismar

Comment: @ethry - that's exactly what I said, most of them are, Safari and Opera being the exceptions I'm aware of.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the last part.

Answer (score 0):

use `<input type="time" >` . In all browsers with time picker (also in iOS) put here a color picker